# Android widget ListView item clicks not working

Tags: android, android-service, android-widget, android-pendingintent, remoteview

So I'm trying to set up a widget with a list but clicks aren't working, so I understand to do this I need a template pending intent as individual items cannot have their own, and then add to the pending intent template using a fill in intent, I've added all this to my app but it still isn't working, I've followed advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441250/listview-widget-with-multiple-pending-intents) and [here](https://joshuadonlan.gitbooks.io/onramp-android/content/widgets/collection_widgets.html) but when I click on an item its just highlighted to show it has registered a click and does nothing but I do get this in the 
logcat

```
08-06 17:02:08.001 2163-3666/? W/Binder: Binder call failed.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 
'com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$ProviderId 
com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$Provider.id' 
on a null object reference
    at 
com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$AppWidgetManagerLocal
.getHostedWidgetPackages(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:4800)
    at 
com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$SecurityPolicy
.resolveValidReportedPackageLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:4637)
    at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService
.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityManagerService.java:531)
    at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager$Stub
.onTransact(IAccessibilityManager.java:71)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:690)
```

so here is my code, my onUpdate method calls a static update widget method that defines my template pending intent, and my onReceive method

**AppWidgetProvider**

```
public class MessageMeAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String TAG = "MsgMeWdgt";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.LAUNCH_ACTIVITY)) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        //String recipientId =  intent.getStringExtra(Constants.FS_ID);
        //String recipientName =  intent.getStringExtra(Constants.FS_NAME);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MessageListActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        //b.putString(Constants.FS_ID, recipientId);
        //b.putString(Constants.FS_ID, recipientName);
        i.putExtras(b);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String toastText = "position is " + bundle.getInt(Constants.LAUNCH_ACTIVITY);
        Toast.makeText(context,toastText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //context.startActivity(i);
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Constants.DONT_LAUNCH_ACTIVITY)){
        //Toast.makeText(context,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                   int appWidgetId) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean userSignedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.SIGNED_IN, false);
    if (userSignedIn){
        //move everything in here after i know its working
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessagingService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_view);
    //populates data
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list,intent);
    //remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_list, intent);
    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_list,R.id.empty);

    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetAdapter.class);
    launchIntent.setAction(Constants.LAUNCH_ACTIVITY);
    launchIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    PendingIntent launchPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launchIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_list, launchPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
           Log.d(TAG,"on update");
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}
```

Then my widget service is standard

```
public class MessagingService extends RemoteViewsService {
private String TAG = "MsgSrvc";
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"item clicked");
    return new WidgetAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
  }
}
```

and then in the getViewAt method of my widget adapter I fill my fill in intent like this

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(Constants.LAUNCH_ACTIVITY, position);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.holder, fillInIntent);
```

in my manifest I'm registering my widget service and the receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.sealstudios.aimessage.MessageMeAppWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/message_me_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MessagingService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this it wasthe intent was pointing to the wrong class so

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetAdapter.class);
```

should have been

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MessageMeAppWidget.class);
```